# How to hide some users to unlogged users

Tags: users, user-roles, user-registration

I have a WordPress site with the [Tiger Theme](https://themeforest.net/item/tiger-social-network-theme-for-companies-professionals/16203995). It's a kind of social site, and there are two types of users: 'Professionals' and 'Corporates'. I would like to hide the 'Corporates' from visitors (with or without an account) that are not logged in. I would like that the corporates profiles are visible only for registered users with approved subscription (Status: ACTIVE).

Is there a way or plugin to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: I am not sure what you're asking here. Please elaborate where users would able to see each other?

Comment: I would like that users unlogged don't see corporates profiles..

Comment: Visitor without an account? And can you provide us a link yo your theme?

Comment: I eidted my question with this info

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't posted any code so I won't be able to precisely post an answer for you, but this it what you can do.

Find the page that is rendering the profiles, open it and add this piece of code in it:

```
<?php 
    $user_info = get_userdata($id);
    $role = $user_info->roles; 
    if ($role =='corporates' && !is_user_logged_in()) { 
        wp_safe_redirect( site_url()); 
        exit;
    } 
?>
```

Which `$id` is the user id of the profile owner, not the visitor.

If you add more technical information about your problem I will update the answer for you.

Comment: Thank's! I adapted this code to my code and it's correct! Many thanks!